# Present Simple Tense with For

Tags: present-tense, time-reference

Is it grammatically correct or colloquial to use "for" with present simple tense as in the following examples :

> I do this business for ten years.
>
> I teach Math for five years.
>
> I run this company for years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. We almost never use the simple present with "for". We can use future or past (*I will be there for an hour*; *I was there for an hour*) but for states or activities that are still continuing, we always use the perfect: usually the perfect continuous (*I have been studying French for two years*), but for verbs which don't normally take continuous forms, the perfect (*I have been here for two years*).

Sometimes both continuous and non-continuous forms are acceptable: *I've watched him for an hour* vs *I've been watching him for an hour*. The latter draws attention to the continuing nature of the watching.

Comment: you probably saw the third example but I would like to ask to ensure , it is not correct, is it ?

Comment: All three of your examples are not idiomatic, except in one context: they are all acceptable in a future sense - laying out the speaker's intentions. "I decide to stay, I run this company for five years, and then I sell out my share".

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to say for, but have the word 'have' in second? i.e

> I have done this business for ten years.
>
> I have taught Math for five years.
>
> I have run this company for years.

I also am not quite sure you would use simple present tense for this; maybe refer to this from **Grammarly**.

> We use the simple present tense when an action is **happening right now**, or when it happens regularly (or unceasingly, which is why it's sometimes called present indefinite). Depending on the person, the simple present tense is formed by using the root form or **by adding ‑s or ‑es to the end.**